# Cayley graph with opposite action: is the group abelian?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, group-actions, cayley-graphs

Let $G$ be a group, let $S$ be a set of generators and let $\Gamma=\Gamma(G,S)$ be the [Cayley graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph), where there is an edge between $g$ and $h$ if and only if $h=gs$ for some $s\in S$.

- We know that the action of $G$ on $\Gamma$ via left multiplication acts on $\Gamma$ via [graph automorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism): if $h=gs$, then for each $a\in G$,
  $$
  ah = a(gs) = (ag)s ,
  $$
  and so $ag$ ahd $ah$ are connected by an edge whenever $g$ and $h$ are.
- Conversely, the action of $G$ on $\Gamma$ via *right* multiplication does not in general induce graph automorphisms:
  $$
  ha = gsa \ne ags ,
  $$
  unless $G$ is abelian.

Now, is the converse true? If the action of $G$ via right multiplication induces graph automorphisms, can we conclude that $G$ is abelian?

Comment: One can choose $S$ to be very big, possibly $G\setminus \{1\}$ so that the Cayley Graph is always a complete digraph. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a bit to kabenyuk's answer, it's actually easy to show that this is equivalent to the connection set being a union of conjugacy classes.
You want $g\sim h\Longleftrightarrow ga\sim ha$ for all $g,h,a\in G$. But this is equivalent to $g^{-1}h\in S\Longleftrightarrow a^{-1}g^{-1}ha\in S$, which is equivalent to $S$ being closed under conjugation.

(Such Cayley graphs are sometimes called normal Cayley graphs, although that terminology can also mean something else.)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is wrong.
Let us take the union of several conjugacy classes in the non-Abelian group G as a generating set:
$S=a_1^G\cup\ldots\cup a_k^G$.
It is easy to see that the action of $G$ via right multiplication induces graph automorphisms. For instance, $G=S_3$, $S=\{(12),(12),(23)\}$.